# Firebase Cloud Firestore: Query isn't updating ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following query:

```
db.collection("Example")
                .whereEqualTo("UserId", currentUser.getUid())
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: " + document.get("UserId") + " => " + document.get("userText"));
                                userIdArrayList.add(document.get("UserId").toString());
                                userTextArrayList.add(document.get("userText").toString());

                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: Error getting documents", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

As the query is iterating through results, I would like it to add the results to an array. However, when I run the code and attempt to print the content of the array list, I am getting and `IndexOutOfBounds` exception despite me looking at `userTextArrayList.get(0);` which should contain a result. I have added the line `Log.i` to check if the code is running successfully and I can see in the Logcat that the data is being pulled from the database. For some reason this code isn't adding the results to the ArrayList.

I'm not sure what else to try and I am unable to find anywhere in the documentation that can assist me with where I have potentially gone wrong.

Please feel free to point me towards the documentation that can assist with the problem if providing the answer is too much bother. I appreciate any guidance anyone can provide.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I am getting an error on the following lines of code:

1. `userIdArrayList.add(document.get("UserId").toString());`
2. `userTextArrayList.add(document.get("userText").toString())`

For some reason these lines aren't adding the data to the array and when I attempt to print the array later in the code (i.e. `Log.i(TAG, "User Text => userTextArrayList.get(0).toString());`), I am recieving and error for `IndexOutOfBounds` - apparently the ArrayList does not contain data despite the above code adding data to the ArrayLists.

Comment: Please mention which line u r getting the error at.

Comment: Apologies. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that this query is asynchronous and the results might not have yet been added to `userTextArrayList` when you execute this log statement `Log.i(TAG, "User Text => userTextArrayList.get(0).toString());`

This log statement needs to be in `onComplete()` as below in order for it to work:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: " + document.get("UserId") + " => " + document.get("userText"));            
            userIdArrayList.add(document.get("UserId").toString());      
            userTextArrayList.add(document.get("userText").toString());
        }
        yourButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: Error getting documents", task.getException());
        yourButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have put this query inside a function which is called at the beginning of the android activity's `onCreate()` method. The `Log.i` code is used when a user presses the button so is called much later than when the query is called so I would expect the ArrayLists to be populated. Going from your solution above, it would seem that you are implying that I should add a button "on click listener" within the query onComplete. I don't believe the above to be a correct solution - sorry, but thank you for your help.

Comment: What you can do is to initialize your button as disabled and enable it only when your ArrayList is updated with the data (see updated answer). That's the only solution that can be suggested considering the very little code that's been shared. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does the `onComplete()` method not make it irrelevant? Surely the `onComplete()` method is only run once the query is complete? Please let me know if I am incorrect.

Comment: "Does the onComplete() method not make it irrelevant?" > Make what irrelevant?

Comment: "Surely the onComplete() method is only run once the query is complete?" Yes but you don't know whether the user presses the button before onComplete() is called or after it. That's why i suggested to keep ur button disabled until onComplete() is called.

Comment: Oh! I see what you are saying. Huge apologies for taking so long! I'll attempt this now and let you know the results.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you for your help.